# Commands after root login not working in terminator terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, expect, terminator

I wrote a script :

```
#! /bin/bash

terminator -x sh -c "expect -c 'spawn su - ;expect Password:;send "your-password\n";interact';df -h;bash "
```

-->this will open up a terminator's terminal with root login , what changes do i need to make, in script so that other commands(eg.df -h) can execute in the terminator's terminal after root login.

Comment: It is working fine. Did you escape the double quotes which are used while sending the password ?

Comment: what is want is, to open up a terminator with root login, which is happening in the above case.And in that terminator df -h should get executed.
When i am trying to do so, only terminator opens up with root login.

Comment: I have tried with my username `su dinesh` (as I don't have root access) and it is executing the `df -h` command and further bash also getting started as well.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info !